# Java Stress Testing Automation for a Web Application

Tags: java, testing, automation, awtrobot

As what the title say, I would like to create a Java application that will automate a stress testing in a specific Web Application of mine. I am looking to use Robot Class.

I have not begun the coding just yet, still researching for the mean time on how to do this. Some say use a Robot class and have read some articles about it and could be useful. My concern for this are:

1. if it will take over my mouse and desktop, basically, does it do it virtually? What I mean about virtually is, does it, for example, opens a browser that I can see it or does it open it on the background?
2. if so,  saying I am testing a Web App what about the sessions of the browser? does it applies the same when I open an actual browser and use it?

Can anyone share some ideas on this? Thanks.

Comment: What is "stress test" in the context of your question? To me it is putting the site under high load with many concurrent users. You don't do that with a single computer.

Comment: Yup, that is what I am trying to do. Load test the server with simultaneous entries. Is this not possible with Robot Class?

Answer (score 0):

There are many online and offline tools available for load testing a web application.

JMeter, WebDriver are two of them

Comment: I am trying JMeter and it look promising. It looks like I wont be developing a new tester for this. Bitter sweet kinda deal. :)